# how to properly use Result.bind

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I am currently trying to implement some validation in my F# program but i'm facing som compile time errors, which I can't solve.
Boiled down, i'm trying to do this

```
let ifFalseThenError x errorMessage = function 
   | true -> Ok x 
   | false -> Error errorMessage
let val1 (initialeSandssynligheder : float[]) =
       initialeSandssynligheder
       |> Seq.sum
       |> (fun x -> x < 2)
       |> (fun x -> ifFalseThenError initialeSandssynligheder "Some error")

let val2 initialeSandssynligheder = 
    initialeSandssynligheder 
    |> Array.exists ((<) 0.0) 
    |> (fun x -> ifFalseThenError initialeSandssynligheder "SomeOtherError")

let beregnAlleOvergangssandsynligheder (initialeSandssynligheder: float[])  : float[] = 
       let initialeSandssynligheder = [|1.0;1.0;1.0;1.0;1.0|] 
       let initssh = initialeSandssynligheder 
                     |> val1
                     |> Result.bind val2  // Error here
       initssh
```

So this my compiler tells me, that I have a type mismatch. I understand, that both val1 and val2 takes a float[] and returns a Result<Float[], String> and I need to compensate for that, when im piping in my val2 and I though I could do that by using Result.bind. What am i misundertanding.

My error:

```
Error   FS0001  Type mismatch. Expecting a
    '(bool -> Result<float [],string>) -> 'a'    
but given a
    'Result<'b,'c> -> Result<'d,'c>'    
The type 'bool -> Result<float [],string>' does not match the type 'Result<'a,'b>'... (Path)
```

So the message is telling my what I though I was compensating for, when adding the Result.bind statement to the last validation

Comment: Please post the compiler errors. Are there more than one? If so, which one is the first error? What does it tell you?

Comment: Thank you, I've just added the compiler error and as I understand it, it is still expecting complaining that the val2 does not take <Float[], String>  as an input

Comment: That's not the only compiler error, is it?

Comment: No correct, but I think I can manage to solve the others, if I solve this.  The same line also gives me these errors: 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error FS0001 Type mismatch. Expecting a
    '(bool -> Result<float [],string>) -> 'a'    
but given a
    'Result<float [],'b> -> Result<'c,'b>'    
The type 'bool -> Result<float [],string>' does not match the type 'Result<float [],'a>' (path)

Comment: and Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error FS0001 Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'float [] -> Result<'a,'b>'    
but given a
    'float [] -> bool -> Result<float [],string>'    
The type 'Result<'a,'b>' does not match the type 'bool -> Result<float [],string>' (path)

Comment: *"I think I can manage to solve the others, if I solve this"* How do you know? The F# compiler is a single-pass compiler, so the first error it encounters will often cause a cascade of other errors. FWIW, the first error in the code you've submitted is in line 7, not 19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in comments there are multiple compilation errors:

1. Incorrect numeric data type
2. Missing arguments to function
3. Wrong return type hint in `beregnAlleOvergangssandsynligheder`

Here's a version that resolves these compilation errors with comments describing where changes were made:

```
let ifFalseThenError x errorMessage =
  function
  | true -> Ok x
  | false -> Error errorMessage

let val1 (initialeSandssynligheder: float array) =
  initialeSandssynligheder
  |> Seq.sum
  |> (fun x -> x < 2.0) // changed to float
  |> (fun x -> ifFalseThenError initialeSandssynligheder "Some error" x) // include x arg

let val2 initialeSandssynligheder =
  initialeSandssynligheder
  |> Array.exists ((<) 0.0)
  |> (fun x -> ifFalseThenError initialeSandssynligheder "SomeOtherError" x) // include x arg

let beregnAlleOvergangssandsynligheder (initialeSandssynligheder: float array) : Result<float array, string> = // Mixing list/array, hint return result
  let initssh =
    initialeSandssynligheder
    |> val1
    |> Result.bind val2 // Error here

  initssh

beregnAlleOvergangssandsynligheder [| 1.0; 1.0; 1.0; 1.0; 1.0 |] // Error because sum > 2
beregnAlleOvergangssandsynligheder [| -1.0 |] // Error because of negative value
beregnAlleOvergangssandsynligheder [| 1.0 |] // Ok
```

I would also look over the usages of array/list/seq, e.g. you are using array's but I'm not seeing any specific need for that here, maybe seq would be enough? Try to settle on the one you need.

Comment: Can I ask a two follow up questions. 

1. You changed the input of beregnAlleOvergangssandsynligheder  from float[] to float array) why is that? 
2. If i later on in the function beregnAlleOvergangssandsynligheder  want to get elements of initssh, how would you do that. Let's say I want a line like:
let plusone = initssh.[0] +1

Comment: Sure thing! `float[]` and `float array` is the same thing and you can use whichever you like, however personally I usually use `float array` to not confuse it with an empty list: `let x = []`.

And array is likely what you want if you want to be able to access it by index like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition on how to use Result.bind is correct.  However, there are a number of errors in your code:

1. The function ifFalseThenError takes a boolean which you're not
   passing by, in both val1, val2.
2. In val1 you need to use a float value, e.g. 2.0 rather than int 2.

Here it's corrected

```
let ifFalseThenError x errorMessage = function 
   | true -> Ok x 
   | false -> Error errorMessage
let val1 (initialeSandssynligheder : float[]) =
       initialeSandssynligheder
       |> Seq.sum
       |> (fun x -> x < 2.0)
       |> (fun x -> ifFalseThenError initialeSandssynligheder "Some error" x)

let val2 initialeSandssynligheder = 
    initialeSandssynligheder 
    |> Array.exists ((<) 0.0) 
    |> (fun x -> ifFalseThenError initialeSandssynligheder "SomeOtherError" x)

let beregnAlleOvergangssandsynligheder (initialeSandssynligheder: float[])  = 
       let initialeSandssynligheder = [|1.0;1.0;1.0;1.0;1.0|] 


       let initssh = initialeSandssynligheder 
                     |> val1 
                     |> Result.bind val2
       initssh
```

ps.  A good way to solve these problems is to add type annotations to all of your functions and parameters.